# Is there a way to remove the source domain from the window title in an out-of-browser Silverlight 3 app?

Tags: silverlight, macos, silverlight-3.0, plist, out-of-browser

We may not have the option to migrate over to Silverlight 4 right away, so I was wondering if anyone found a way to remove the source domain name from the window's title for out-of-browser Silverlight 3 applications.  Our window title currently looks like this: "My App - localhost."

Under Mac, I found the Info.plist file in the application bundle and found where you can set the `Bundle name` property as well as `TrimmedSourceDomain`.  Unfortunately, when I clear the `TrimmedSourceDomain` property, the title looks like "My App -," and if I delete the property entirely, the application doesn't launch.  I assume similar problems would occur under Windows.  Have any of you found a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is simply "no."  It looks like it still can't be done under Silverlight 4,  either.  You can, under SL 4 do custom Chrome, but that's the closest thing to do that I can find.

Answer (score 0):

Sliverlight 4 specifically mentions "chrome" as one of its new features.  I've heard recently from an MS Developer Evangelist that the new chrome feature includes not having any at all.  My hunch, therefore, is that SL3 OOB applications cannot have their chrome removed.

Comment: Sorry, but my question wasn't about removing Chrome, so I didn't accept this answer.